# Stream groupBy to nested maps with casting

Tags: java, java-stream, java-9

Need to calculate total number by gender from below structure of nested Maps. But as data stored as `Object` need to cast it at every iteration. After grouping not able to cast last leaf Map to calculate and filter date object.

```
Map<String, Object> total = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> mass = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> ny = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> male = new HashMap<>();
male.put("2021", 17);
male.put("2020", 98);
male.put("lastdate", new Date());
Map<String, Object> female = new HashMap<>();
female.put("2021", 12);
female.put("2020", 87);
female.put("lastdate", new Date());
mass.put("male", male);
mass.put("female", female);
ny.put("male", male);
ny.put("female", female);
total.put("MA", mass);
total.put("NY", ny);
```

Applied below stream,

```
Object mm = total.values().stream().map(x -> (Map<String, Object>) x)
            .map(Map::entrySet).flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey),
                    Collectors.toMap(x -> (Map<String, Object>) x) // Not Working both toMapping() too
            );

/*
Final required output as Map
male=115
female=99
 */
```

Comment: Having `Object` as the value definition is not optimal. Please go ahead and use the proper typing for each value of each `Map` object.

Comment: @akortex I agree with you, as this is legacy DS and need to apply solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a rather unusual way to store data. I would recommend you to implement appropriate classes, such as person with the appropriate fields like gender, age, weight etc.

But if you want to stick with your data structure, something like below should work:

```
Map<String,Integer> result =
total.values()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> (Map<String,Object>) e)
        .findAny()
        .get()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        m -> ((Map<String,Object>) m.getValue()).values()
                                .stream()
                                .filter(Integer.class::isInstance)
                                .mapToInt(Integer.class::cast)
                                .sum()));
```